# PyQt Creates Seperate Window For Button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Hi recently I started experimenting with the PyQt5 GUI library since Tkinter doesn't look very modern or nice. I am trying to create a very simple window with a button on it, but for some reason it opens a new window for the button. How can I solve this? Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
window.setWindowTitle("UI")
window.show()


btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Test")
btn.resize(100,100)
btn.move(100,100)
btn.show()


(app.exec_())
```

I am aware that I should be using classes for the GUI, but I'd like to learn the basics before I start doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a widget like the QPushButton to be part of a window, the widget must be fulfilled:

1. be child of the window or
2. be a child of some child from the window or
3. it is part of a layout that belongs to the window.

In your case QPushButton does not meet any of it so it will be a new window.So it can be solved using the 1 or 3 rule:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
    window.setWindowTitle("UI")

    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Test", window)
    btn.resize(100,100)
    btn.move(100,100)

    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    window.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 300)
    window.setWindowTitle("UI")

    btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Test")

    lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(window)
    lay.addWidget(btn)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```